# What is the behavior of nested try-catch blocks regarding object unwinding order?

Tags: c++, try-catch

EDIT: It turned out I was confused by the destruction of `f` second argument which is a copy of `tmp`. See my answer below for details.

So I was experimenting with C++ unwinding and came to this strange behavior where we have a nested try-catch blocks and in the outer one we have constructed an object. It seems that this object is destructed at point of catching the exception in one of the inner try-catch handlers.

Also if we use dynamic memory allocation as I've shown in this example (we use `new` in the constructor and `delete` in the destructor) the program seems to produce diagnostic message at runtime.

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    test(int);
    ~test() throw(int);
    int *b;
};

void f5() {
    if (!printf(""))
        throw 9;
}

test f(int, test) throw(int) { test tmp(6); f5();  return tmp; }

test::test(int a) : b(new int(a)) { printf("constructor test@%d\n", *b); }

test::~test() throw(int)
{
    printf("destructor test@%d\n", *b);
    delete b;
}

int main() {
    test tmp(0);
    try {
        test tmp(1);
        try {
            f(7, tmp);
        }
        catch (int) {
            printf("catch(int)@%d\n", 2);
            try {
                test tmphandler(3); f(7, tmp);
            }
            catch (int) {
                printf("catch(int)@%d\n", 4);
            }
        }

        printf("b = %d\n", *tmp.b);

        f(7, tmp);
    }
    catch (int) { printf("catch(int)@%d\n", 5); }
}
```

Here is the [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EmzgawJAXhgTBtWQ) output of this program:

```
*** Error in `./prog.exe': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000020ee180 ***
....back-trace of addresses
constructor test@0
constructor test@1
constructor test@6
destructor test@6
destructor test@1
catch(int)@2
constructor test@3
constructor test@6
destructor test@6
destructor test@3
destructor test@33722768
```

I'm struggling to understand why at the point of catch @ 2 the object in the outer try scope is destructed (i.e the object created @ 1).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the standard, but recently I was reading Deitel's book about C++, here's a paragraph from it:

> 17.4 Stack Unwinding
>
> When an exception is thrown but not caught in a particular scope, the function-call stack is “unwound,” and an attempt is made to catch the exception in the next outer try ... catch block. Unwinding the function call stack means that the function in which the exception was not caught terminates, all local variables that have completed initialization in that function are destroyed and control returns to the statement that originally invoked that function. If a try block encloses that statement, an attempt is made to catch the exception. If a try block does not enclose that statement, stack unwinding occurs again. If no catch handler ever catches this exception, the program terminates.

I hope this answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of I was missing a copy constructor hence the diagnostic message at run-time. Second of all - the destructor was actually called for the argument of `f` that gets copied from `tmp` and so the value of `1` gets printed in the destruction of said object which is correctly destructed at the point of catching the exception. Here is the non-confusing fixed variant:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    test(const test&);
    test(int);
    ~test() throw(int);
    int *b;
};

void f5() {
    if (!printf(""))
        throw 9;
}

test f(int, test) throw(int) { test tmp(6); f5();  return tmp; }

test::test(int a) : b(new int(a)) { printf("constructor test@%d\n", *b); }

test::test(const test& a) : b(new int(7)) {}

test::~test() throw(int)
{
    printf("destructor test@%d\n", *b);
    delete b;
}

int main() {
    test tmp(0);
    try {
        test tmp(1);
        try {
            f(7, tmp);
        }
        catch (int) {
            printf("catch(int)@%d\n", 2);
            try {
                test tmphandler(3); f(7, tmp);
            }
            catch (int) {
                printf("catch(int)@%d\n", 4);
            }
        }

        printf("b = %d\n", *tmp.b);

        f(7, tmp);
    }
    catch (int) { printf("catch(int)@%d\n", 5); }
}
```

With output of:

```
constructor test@0
constructor test@1
constructor test@6
destructor test@6
destructor test@7
catch(int)@2
constructor test@3
constructor test@6
destructor test@6
destructor test@7
destructor test@3
catch(int)@4
b = 1
constructor test@6
destructor test@6
destructor test@7
destructor test@1
catch(int)@5
destructor test@0
```